# First time deploying ASP.NET web api, ran into '/' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

This is the first time i am deploying an ASP web api. The api runs smoothly in Debug/Release section but i got an error when first deployed it.

libzkfpcsharp is a dll that supports only x86. I changed  The configuration properties to x86 to support the dll but i still get an error. Anyone knows how to deal with this?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'libzkfpcsharp' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'libzkfpcsharp' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'libzkfpcsharp' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'libzkfpcsharp' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +232
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +113
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +23
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'libzkfpcsharp' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +767
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +256
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +287
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +69
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +137
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +854

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'libzkfpcsharp' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to change you App.domain with in IIS to run in 32 bit mode

[image]

Comment: Where can i find the Advanced Settings window? The one i found didn't have such options.

Comment: Open IIS –>Go to current server –> Application Pools –>Select the application pool your 32-bit application will run under, Click Advanced setting, then set Enable 32-bit Applications to True.

Comment: I am handing over this local api to a company. Is there any simpler way to deploy a web api?

Comment: How did you deploy web api? [Publish And Host ASP.NET Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/publish-and-host-Asp-Net-web-api/).

Comment: You are going to need to ask your provider, to see how you can have your web site run in a 32 bit app pool